# ajax Uncaught ReferenceError: field_inputs is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

it is custom form and i dont know why all time i have "Uncaught ReferenceError: field_inputs is not defined" error

If you also have a way to shorten the code I'd love to know how

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        
         $(document).ready(function () {
          $( ".form" ).change(function() {
           $( ".addfromform" ).empty();
           field_include();
          });
         });
         
         function field_include()
         {
          var form_id = $( ".form" ).val();
          
          $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/field_include.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
           form_id : form_id
          },
          success: function(data) 
          {
            var fields = data;
            var field = fields.split(";").filter(Boolean);
            $.each(field, function(i, val){
             var field_val = val.split(",");
             $( ".addfromform" ).append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-lg-2 control-label mt10">'+field_val[2]+'</label><div class="col-xs-10"><label for="'+field_val[1]+'" class="field prepend-icon"><input type="'+field_val[0]+'" name="'+field_val[1]+'" id="'+field_val[1]+'" class="gui-input" placeholder="'+field_val[3]+'" autocomplete="off"><label for="'+field_val[1]+'" class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></label></label></div></div>').fadeIn('slow');
            
            
             if (input_ids != null)
             {
              var input_ids = ""+input_ids+","+field_val[1]+"";
              $(".date").data("input_name", ""+input_ids+"");
             }
             else
             {
              var input_ids = ""+field_val[1]+"";
              $(".date").data("input_name", ""+input_ids+"");
             }
            });
           }
          });
         }
         
         function save_guest()
         {
          var field_names = $(".date").data("input_name");
          
          var field_name = field_names.split(",").filter(Boolean);
          $.each(field_name, function(i, input_val){
           
           if(typeof(field_inputs) != "undefined" && field_inputs !== null)
           {
            var input_date = $( "."+input_val+"" ).val();
            var field_inputs = ""+field_inputs+""+input_val+","+input_date+";";
           }
           else
           {
            var input_date = $( "."+input_val+"" ).val();
            var field_inputs = ""+input_val+","+input_date+";";
           }
          });
          
          $.ajax({
           url: 'ajax/save_new_guest.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
            field : field_inputs
           },
           success: function(data) 
           {
            document.location.href="../../guest.php";
           }
          });
         }

        </script>
```

```html
<button onclick="save_guest();" class="button btn-primary"> Add guest </button>
```

I'm new topic AJAX jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put `field_inputs` outside the `each` function so that your `ajax` can access the variable

```
function save_guest()
    {
    var field_inputs = null;
    var field_names = $(".date").data("input_name");
    var field_name = field_names.split(",").filter(Boolean);
    $.each(field_name, function(i, input_val){
        if(typeof(field_inputs) != "undefined" && field_inputs !== null)
        {
            var input_date = $( "."+input_val+"" ).val();
            field_inputs = ""+field_inputs+""+input_val+","+input_date+";";
        }
        else
        {
            var input_date = $( "."+input_val+"" ).val();
            field_inputs = ""+input_val+","+input_date+";";
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/save_new_guest.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            field : field_inputs
        },
        success: function(data) 
        {
            document.location.href="../../guest.php";
        }
    });
}
```